# Редирект через URL

Tags: php, mysql

Предположим есть [site.com](http://nowhere), где используются url по документам `/news`, `/main`, `/qeqqe`
При регистрации у пользователя появляется свой `id`, и url на свой профиль `/user1`
У пользователя есть возможность выбрать свой адрес, например `/doofy` вместо `/user1`

Полагаю организовать это можно через редирект при 404 ошибке, но как проверять существующие страницы и как хранить все занятые адреса?

По какой схеме работает тот же [ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999), когда открывает профиль по id **186999** пользователя? Для примера у меня получилось что-то такое. Не знаю насколько всё это правильно и в том ли направлении я иду.

<sub>[**httpd.conf**](http://nowhere)</sub>
`ErrorDocument 404 /url.php`

<sub>[**url.php**](http://nowhere)</sub>

```
$uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1, 32);

if($uri != 'doofy') {
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK', true, 200);
    $user = $uri;
    require_once('user.php');
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found', true, 404);
    require_once('404.php');
}
```

---

Захотел пользователь использовать свой адрес `site.com/shit`, а вдруг уже будет создана папка `shit`. Как это проверить?

Comment: Лучше парсить запрос с помощью preg_match, результаты парсинга помещать в $_GET и работать с этим по стандартной схеме.

Comment: @ilyaplot, мне нужен развёрнутый ответ, примеры, почему лучше регуляркой, варианты, как проще и т.д.

Comment: @ilyaplot Нельзя ничего помещать в `$_GET` самому тогда теряеться его смысл, вылизают баги типо я отправил `?test=mytest` а в php получил `$_GET['test'] => don't my test`

Comment: @Naumov Я использовал логику фреймворка Yii 1.x Сейчас Вы говорите, что нельзя так делать всему Yii сообществу.

Answer (score 1):

есть таблица например `user_rewrite_uri` в mysql

```
| entity_id    |user_id|user_url_key  |
 ------------   -------------------
| 1    | 11     | myName.html    |
 -------------   -------------------
| 2    | 12     | ohterName.html |
 -----------   ---------------------
```

Все запросы идут на index.php или какой либо роутер где просто берём `key` в нашем случае `example.ru/user/myName.html` 
что сответствует `$key = 'myName.html'` выбираем его с таблицы. и получаем `id` в данном случае `11` и преобразовываем запрос в что то похожее на `example.ru/user/id/11` и далее выполняем рендер. `404` ошибка должны быть после всего когда ничего не найденно ибо не прямолинейная логика запутает в дальнейшем. Легче воспринимаеться такая схема
`url -> user key || id -> render || 404` а не `url -> id -> 404 -> user key -> render || 404` в последним случае отловить действительно 404 ошибку сложнее.

update для конкретизации приведу пример роутинга в своём небольшом личном проэкте полностью можно сдесь посмотреть https://github.com/lnroma/ncms/ .

```
 /**
 * run application
 * @return bool
 */
static public function runApplet() {
    self::dispathEvent('run_application_before',array()); // это эвент для обсервера не обращаем внимания
    $params = self::getParams(); // берём параметра из url смотри ниже
    // алгоритм компиляции и проверки config'ов модулей
    self::$_controllObject = self::loadController($configModul,$params);
    self::dispathEvent('run_application_after',array());
    return true;
}
```

далее берём параметры

```
/**
 * get params request
 * @return array
 */
static public function getParams() {
    $result = array();
    $baseUri = parse_url(self::getBaseUrl());
    $requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if(isset($baseUri['path']) && $baseUri['path'] != '/') {
        $requestUri = str_replace($baseUri['path'],'',$requestUri);
    }
    $params = explode('/',trim($requestUri,'/'));
    // тут был алгоритм генерации имени модуля, контроллера, action
    // generate params
    // $i=3 так как ранее первые 3 параметра это соответственно модуль, контроллер и action
    for ( $i=3; $i<count($params); $i++ ) {
        if( $i%2 != 0 ) {
            if(isset($params[$i+1])) {
                $result[$params[$i]] = $params[$i+1];
            }
        }
    }
    // $result это array вида 'param' => '1', 'param2' => 2 и т.д.
    return $result;
}
```

далее идёт инстанс контроллера

```
/**
 * call controller action
 * @param $objectController
 * @param $params
 * @return mixed
 * @throws Exception_Notfound
 */
static protected function _callControllerAction($objectController,$params) {
    $params = Core_App::getParams();
    $action = $params['action'].'Action';
    if(!method_exists($objectController,$action)) {
        throw new Exception_Notfound('Page not found');
    }
    call_user_func(array($objectController,$action));
    return $objectController;
}
```

Далее идёт выполнение запрошеного action'а в котором собственно будет доступен массив параметров

`Core::app()->getParams()['userKey'];` далее уже реализовываем выборку с базой, у меня их 2-ве `mongo` и `mysql`, так как надо иметь целостность определённую для url я использую `mysql`. В приложение есть функционал по alisam для страниц и модулей. Механизм до безумия прост. И построен в основном на обсерверах модулей

```
  'router_load' => array(
                'observer' => 'Pages_Model_Observer',
                'method' => array(
                    'aliasForPage',
                    'aliasMenu'
                )
            ),
```

это кусок конфига модуля он говорит что после загрузки роутера запустить методы `aliasForPage` и `aliasMenu` в классе `Pages_Model_Observer` расмотрим `aliasForPage`;

```
 /**
     * router for page
     * @param $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function aliasForPage($data)
    {
        /** @var Driver\Manager $connect */
        $connect = Core_Model_Mongo::getConnect();
        $man = new MongoDB\Driver\Query(
            array(
                'key' => $this->_getPath()
            )
        );
        $collection = $connect->executeQuery(Config_Db::getConf()['mongodb']['db'] . '.pages', $man);
        if (count($collection->toArray())) {
            $data = array(
                'controller' => 'pages',
                'controllerName' => 'view',
                'action' => 'index',
                'id' => $this->_getPath()
            );
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

По сути в методе производиться проверка есть ли этот url в бызе, если нет то отправляем алгоритм выполняться дальше, если же есть то мы говорим что он должен запустить следующий модуль, с параметром `id` там указывает hash монго db. После запускаеться уже контроллер который генерирует `view` страницы исходя из данных полученых посредством id.

Comment: Что-то не понятно, как `key` получить, в каком документе, при каких обстоятельствах, через `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`? Почему нужен `entity_id`, если можно в той же строке в таблице достать id пользователя по его `url_key`?

Comment: @Doofy `entity_id` для более удобного выполнения административных действий, удаление, изменение  и т.д. можно и не использовать.

Comment: Тоесть то, что называется роутингом и используется в таких случаях и я угадал со своим примером отправкой заголовка 200 или 404? Кстати в vk неужели тоже самое? Как тогда проверять существующие реальные страницы?

Comment: вы рендерите(генерируете) страницу, не просто отбражаете php или html файлик.

Comment: Генерируется ведь страница по шаблону php документа через `require_once('user.php');`

Comment: Да конечно шаблон а у каждого он одинаков, а если не одинаков тогда можно какую то опцию ввести, но по сути представление юзера будет иметь одинаковый набор данных. @Doofy

Comment: Однако, часть вопросов всё-таки осталась. А, ответ обновил, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: @Doofy я думаю у вас больше их появилось

Comment: Было очень интересно посмотреть на чужой проект. Суть ясна, как раз та часть про разбор url. Кое-что я упускаю из основ, нужно получить информацию про `public`, `static` и `protected`

Comment: @Doofy Пишите с удовольствием отвечу, `public`, `static` и `protected` это области видимости. Так как использую ооп но и без ооп можно. Но тогда будет много повторяющегося кода.

Answer (score 0):

Приведу пример реализации роутинга

```php
function error404()
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found', true, 404);
    require_once('404.php');
    exit();
}


if (empty($_GET['user']) && !preg_match("#^/users/(?P<user>\w+)#u", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)) {
    error404();
}

foreach ($matches as $param => $value) {
    if (is_numeric($param)) {
        continue;
    }

    $_GET[$param] = $value;
}

// Допустим, феункция getUser($user) получает профиль пользователя по username. Если вернет false, значит, юзера не существует.
if ($user=getUser($_GET['user'])===false) {
    error404();
}

// Ошибок нет, работаем с профилем пользователя ($user)
```

Comment: Лучше применить принципы ооп и не переписывать массив `$_GET`.

Comment: @Naumov, думаю что `$_GET` здесь вообще неуместен. Ссылка должна выглядеть `site.com/doofy`, а не `site.com?user=doofy` или `site.com/users/doofy`

Comment: preg_match следует выполнять, если $_GET['user'] пуст, а дальше просто работать с $_GET. Поправил ответ с учетом этого момента. Если обратиться к скрипту по адресу `/users/doofy`, получим $_GET['user'] = doofy, точно так же, как и в случае обращения по адресу `?user=doofy`

Comment: @Naumov Я не вижу необходимости ООП в данном конкретном примере. Вполне возможно, что скрипты обрастут логикой в дальнейшем, но ООП нужно понимать. В рамках данного вопроса ООП может только усложнить понимание ответа.

Comment: При `/users/doofy` выходит ошибка 404, это ведь не тоже самое что `?user=doofy` и нельзя получить `$_GET['user']`

Comment: Почему не то же самое? Вот тут `$_GET[$param] = $value;` Же запишется 'doofy' в $_GET['user']. Возможно, вторая проверка выдает 404?

Comment: Создал папку users, поместил в неё index.php. При обращении к users/doofy он читает документ index.php в папке doofy, такой папки нет, естественно 404, разве нет?

Comment: Так папки может и не быть. Используйте rewrite на index.php в корневой директории

Comment: Я понял в чём соль, мне не нужен `$_GET`, всё что написал в вопросе уже работает. Мне всё интересно как запросами проверять существующие папки, такие как `/users/` и есть ли в них файл  `index.php`. Если проверять на наличие файла, то какая-то бурда получается

Comment: Проверять наличие файла должен web сервер. Посмотрите как это сделано для yii. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/quickstart.apache-nginx-config Для моего предложенного варианта должно работать.