# Области видимости

Tags: php

В каких случаях следует применять области видимости?
`public` `static` `protected` `private`

Comment: Может кто-нибудь объяснить в каких ситуациях это использовать? Желательно с примерами и пояснениями

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Области видимости помогают вам определить, что относится к "потрошкам" реализации, а что нет. Публичная область видимости говорит всем остальным: смотрите, я предоставляю вот этот функционал:

```
class RepositoryFactory 
{
    public function getRepository(string clazz)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Все методы, которые относятся к внутренностям проекта, должны быть private или protected - это не защита от хокиров, это способ скрыть ненужное от тех, кто использует ваш класс

```
class RepositoryFactory
{
    private function checkClassExistence(string clazz) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

В данном случае указанный метод вряд ли будет интересен внешнему миру, он нужен только для помощи публичным методам, поэтому он скрывается.

Разница между protected и private заключается лишь в том, что protected можно переопределить в классе-наследнике, таким образом тот же RepositoryFactory может проводить какие-то свои внутренние проверки прежде чем предпринимать какие-то действия - и эти проверки могут быть расширены или сужены в классе-наследнике. Чтобы предоставить такую возможность наследникам, метод объявляется как protected:

```
class RepositoryFactory
{
    protected function isValidRepositoryClazz(string clazz) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Обычно такой функционал требуется в очень редких случаях, и практически вся внутрянка выносится в `private`.

Модификатор static не является модификатором области видимости и управляет контекстом, в котором существует поле или метод. В обычном случае мы оперируем в контексте конкретного экземпляра класса, в случае употребления static мы оперируем в контексте самого класса; таким образом статические методы не имеют this и могут быть вызваны из любой части программы, а статические переменные существуют только в единственном экземпляре во всей программе (в отличие от полей экземпляра, привязанных к конкретному экземпляру).

Comment: Значит *public* будет доступен извне, а что касается только самого класса будет *private* или *protected*. А от кого мы скрываем ненужное в классе? Понятно что не от хокиров и всё же

Comment: @Doofy: От вас самого, разумеется. Вы сегодня помните, что и как можно менять, а через год забудете.

Comment: @VladD, первые годы так и было, пока не научился держать код в чистоте с минимум комментариев. Ну а пока не могу придумать применение для класса

Comment: @Doofy: Хорошо вам! А я по сих пор не могу запомнить в старых проектах, что к чему. А вот с `private` сразу понятно: не разрешено — нельзя трогать, компилятор не даст. (А если в проекте ещё и много людей...)

Comment: @VladD, ну а как насчёт [этого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539000/206959) ответа. Для чего `static public function getParams()`, а не просто `function getParams()`?

Comment: Все равно будет забываться, и очень быстр. С общей сутью понятно, но детали реализации надолго в голове не задержать. Кроме того это попросту комфортно и логично. И не только для себя, но и для любых других разработчиков, которые будут работать с кодом.Одно дело иметь портянку доступных методов класса, часть их которых явна не должна быть доступна извне просто так, другое дело иметь несколько говорящих методов, совершенно не заботясь о деталях их реализации.

Comment: @DanielOlivo, вот-вот, от говнокода нужно избавляться, писать как можно понятнее. Даже такая формальность как табуляция, вместо пробелов - уже приятно. Вот я и хочу выяснить, для чего классы со всеми областями. Неужто для понимания кода другим и себе?

Comment: @Doofy: `static` — это отдельная история. Тут вопрос в том, какие _сущности_ описывает объект, и относится ли метод логически к отдельной сущности, или ко всем им сразу. Как-то так. Звучит расплывчато, я знаю.

Comment: @Doofy, не только. Я на словах попробую пример привести. Вот есть у тебя в классе несколько полей типа int к примеру, и логика работы твоего класса в том числе включает то, что эти поля должны быть в диапазоне [1; 5] к примеру.Если бы эти поля были публичными, то из внешнего кода была бы доступна возможность хоть в 999 установить и все, логику работы класса это нарушает. А так делаешь их приватными, и публичный метод сеттер, который не позволяет установить значения вне диапазона. Все счастливы. Всего один пример, а подобного можно сотни придумать.

Comment: @VladD, темно очень :)

Comment: @DanielOlivo, картина проясняется. Но эту логику всё же извне нужно запустить. Для этого и нужен *public*?

Comment: @Doofy, да, public это то, что формирует _интерфейс_ объекта. Его реализация это сугубо его дело, а интерфейс занимается именно наглядным и достаточным взаимодействием с пользователем, позволяя ему только то, что нужно.

Comment: @Doofy от того, кто этот класс будет использовать. Все что в private/protected - это внутренние методы, не возвращающие конечный результат, и потому неинтересные для внешнего мира. Чтобы они банально не мешались под ногами и не выпадали в автокомплите IDE, их проще скрыть.

Comment: @Etki, не мог бы ты добавить или изменить ответ с примером логики, для наглядности?

Comment: @Doofy, `код в чистоте с минимум комментариев` — не соглашусь с вами по поводу комментариев — по мне, так коментарии очень помогают, даже если код очевиден. За счёт контраста подсветки комментариев вы их и читаете, читаете как «произведение» (логику), а не как набор иснтрукций при изучении чистого кода.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, когда комментариев много, нужные теряются в массе тех, которые комментируют итак понятные вещи, но тема не об этом

Answer (score 3):

**Мой ответ является небольшим дополнением к другим. Это всего лишь попытка провести ассоциацию с объектами в реальном мире, на основе которого и было задумано ООП. Прошу рассматривать повествование с учётом этой позиции.**

---

Существует множество различных формальных объяснений, зачем нужно ограничивать самого себя в доступе к тем или иным членам и методам класса, но вопросы об этой необходимости с завидной регулярностью всплывают один за другим. Тогда, возможно, при объяснении сути следует пойти иным путём.

Если предметом обсуждения является некий объект, то почему бы не представить ему прототип, существующий в реальном мире. Пусть это будет автомобиль.

**Область видимости "public"**

Представьте, что на заводе вдруг решили сделать абсолютно все детали машины доступными водителю без необходимости залезать далеко в недра механизма. Двигатель застучал? Только руку протяни, да затяни какой-нибудь торчащий на виду болт, - все дела. Масло закончилось? Лей прямо в салоне в какую-нибудь выглядывающую из бардачка трубку. Отвалился глушитель? Зачем лезть под машину и что-то приваривать, когда можно просто прицепить шланг одним концом к выходной трубе, а другой высунуть в форточку. Все болты, все гайки, пружины и прочие детали, всё это торчит наружу, весело поблескивая на солнце или хмурясь вместе с водителем в непогожий день.

Страшно даже представить, какой бы монстр в итоге получился, если бы данная фантазия оказалась реальной. Вполне резонно предположить, что таковой агрегат даже не сдвинулся бы с места. А всё потому, что во всем многообразии доступных к управлению и настройке частей лишь малая доля относится непосредственно к управлению движением, которое и осуществляет водитель. Грубо говоря, руль, педали и вперёд, а есть ли в аккумуляторе заряд или нет, водителя должно обеспокоить только в том случае, если машина не заведётся.

**Область видимости "private"**

Водителя, как пользователя механизма, не должно заботить, какие внутренние процессы протекают в той или иной части последнего. Водитель сконцентрирован на движении, на том, чтобы случайно не отвлечься, а заодно и не представиться в случае потери контроля над ситуацией.

Тем не менее, ситуация меняется, когда наступает время технического обслуживания. Водитель приезжает в автомастерскую и там за его автомобиль берётся команда профессиональных техников. Разумеется, если машина прошла огонь, воду и даже медные трубы, то в этой ситуации техники могут не взяться за работу и весело предложат к рассмотрению вопрос на предмет следования к ближайшей свалке. Ну или на завод, который является гением механического чуда.

**Область видимости "protected"**

Однако часть работ по восстановлению и даже модернизации автомобиля, подкованные мастера выполнить могут. Например, повесят дезодорант на лобовое стекло в салоне. Эта маленькая специализирующая деталь существенно изменит настроение водителя к лучшему, поскольку сделает управление автомобилем ещё более удобным и комфортным. Также специальной правке могут подвергнуться и руки самого водителя, если они, по мнению техников, растут совсем не из того места, что потребно при осуществлении безопасного дорожного движения.

**Ключевое слово "static"**

Однажды переиграв в компьютерные игры, юный водитель может вдруг решить, что он grand thief auto и начать залезать в чужие автомобили, как если бы они были его. При этом нарушителя не будет интересовать то, что документы оформлены на совсем иных людей. Он просто пользуется машинами тогда, когда хочет. И если в реальной жизни такое поведение может привести к серьёзным последствиям, в мире кода это вполне допустимый творцом приём. А уж когда и чем ограничить поведение подопытного творец обычно решает не сильно напрягаясь и за очередной чашкой свежемолотого кофе.

Comment: Очень интересная метафора. Только вот со *static* всё равно не понял

Comment: @Doofy, представьте, что `static` - это этакий коммунизм. Вы можете выйти на улицу и прокатиться на любой свободной машине. Вы не покупали её в автосалоне, не являетесь её владельцем, но тем не менее можете на ней ездить, не нарушая закон.

Comment: @alexis031182, можно уточнить? Я возможно сам не до конца понимаю внутренности статика. Представленная аналогия в том, что статик это когда у каждого объекта есть нечто полностью общее, и это так, но получается, что статик это уровень объекта все равно. Может я неправильно аналогию понял, тяжеловато воспринимается. Я считал, что статик это контекст самой сущности класса, которому не нужен ни один объект вообще, хотя они и могут быть, что-то на уровне меты. В аналогии с автомобилями не могу придумать пример, при котором не нужно существование автомобилей вообще.

Comment: Если написать класс, в котором переменная будет *static*, то при создании новых экземпляров класса переменная не будет меняться. `class A { static $a = 1; $a++; }` при вызове `$b = new A;` и `$c = new A;` будет одна и та же `$a`?

Comment: @Doofy, да, но она даже без переменных будет существовать с доступом через имя класса.

Comment: @DanielOlivo, тоесть тут даже статик не нужен?

Comment: @DanielOlivo, у Вас правильное понимание, это несовершенство моей аналогии.

Comment: @Doofy, нужен. Ты все правильно написал, просто есть возможность получить доступ к $a через A::$a.

Answer (score 1):

В таких же, как и в других языках. public для морды объекта/класса, то есть то, что доступно пользователям и наследникам, protected в случае, если не нужен доступ извне объектов/класса, но необходимо иметь доступ в наследниках, private для всего остального. static это члены на уровне класса, а не объекта, к примеру какие-либо вспомогательные методы, поля, целые классы, объекты которых не требуется создавать и т.д. А вообще это все в начальное литературе по ооп гораздо лучше расписано.

Comment: Я читал про их обозначения и для чего они, но не могу понять в каких ситуациях это использовать. PHP для меня сейчас просто как серверная сторона и я не могу представить зачем нужно защищать переменные. Поэтому такие ответы "*private для всего остального*" меня ничему не учат :(